# Probability that Amy gets more heads than Bob?

Tags: probability

Say that Amy tosses a coin 6 times, and Bob tosses a coin 5 times. What's the probability that Amy gets more heads than Bob does?

Comment: @RushabhMehta yes, I have. I wouldn't be asking otherwise! I was thinking that I could break it down case by case(i.e., Bob gets 0 heads, 1 heads, 2....5 heads) and then adding the probabilities that Amy has more, but I was wondering if there were a more efficient solution.

Comment: @JustinDee "*Have you tried this yourself?*"  ... "*yes, I have.  I wouldn't be asking othewise!*"   You should when posting a problem include what you have tried and where you got stuck in the main post *before* being asked about it.

Comment: @JMoravitz okay, thank you very much! Next time, I will include my thought process and where I'm stuck! But I do think the question was unnecessary and a little rude, since for me it wasn't that basic.

Comment: @JustinDee I think it's worth noting the number of posts we get on this site essentially asking us to do work for them. The only way we know you've given the problem a go is through your own efforts. That's why the "how to ask a good question" page makes such a big deal out of this. I apologize if you find it rude, but please do take time to read through the site guidelines to ensure the quality of your posts.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Okay, noted for next time!

Comment: Arguably more important than just filtering out questions from people who aren't willing to put in any effort of their own, by asking for what the user has tried and where they got stuck and seeing their response we can know where to begin an explanation.  Some times all that needs to be pointed out is a small arithmetic error and the question asker otherwise has a firm grasp on all relevant material.  Other times the asker does not understand fundamental concepts and definitions that are clear prerequisites to answer the question, for example not even knowing what a probability is.

Comment: Understanding what the question asker knows allows us to formulate an answer that is going to actually be helpful rather than an answer that on one extreme needlessly wastes time with mundane topics or on the other extreme skips and glosses over steps and definitions that shouldn't have been.

Comment: @JMoravitz I understand and I appreciate your taking the time. I have only been on this site a few times and so I'm unfamiliar with the "rules" so to speak. Like I said, I will keep it in mind for future questions.